# The value of the integral of $f(\zeta)/(\zeta-z)$ for a function holomorphic in exterior domain

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a bounded analytic function on the domain $\{z ∈ C : |z| > 1\}$.
(a) Prove that $\lim_{z→∞} f(z)$ exists.
(b) Let $L$ denote the limit in (a), and let $Γ_R$ denote a circle $|ζ| = R > 1.$ Show
￼that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_{Γ_R}\frac{f(ζ)}{ζ - z} dζ = f(z)−L,\quad  |z|>R,$$
￼￼where the contour $Γ_R$ is traversed in the clockwise direction.

#### Progress

I want to make the change of variables $ζ = 1/w$.  Then I get the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_{Γ_{1/R}}\frac{f(1/w)}{w(1-wz)} dζ$.  But then I get the wrong answer, so this substitution must be wrong and I am not seeing why.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The change of variables $\zeta=1/w$ is a good idea. It implies the existence of limit in (a) by the Riemann removability theorem.

Accounting for the derivative  $d\zeta = -dw/w^2$ I arrive at 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}\, d\zeta 
=  -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=1/R}\frac{f(1/w)}{w^2(1/w - z)}\, dw $$
where the second integral is traversed *counterclockwise* (the first one was clockwise, as stated in the problem). The inversion changed the direction of travel along the circle.

Now it would be a good idea to separate the kernel into partial fractions: 
$$
\frac{1}{w(1-wz)} = \frac{1}{w} + \frac{z}{1-wz} = \frac{1}{w} - \frac{1}{w-1/z} 
$$
Split the integral accordingly, and apply the Cauchy integral formula to each part. (It may help to introduce $g(w)=f(1/w)$ to brings things exactly in line with the formula.)